# How can I send event from my ActorRef to all created children with akka fsm?

Tags: java, events, akka, fsm, tell

I'm using AKKA fsm with java.
I'm trying to send message to all the children ever created by my actorRef.
Lets say for event X my actorRef create new FSM, but didn't save it in a struct.
and for event Y I would like to send this event to all my "sons" (which created before by me, but didn't saved).
Does someone have an idea how can I access to all my child? and "tell" them the event?

Answer (score 1):

You can get an Iterable with all children of the current actor by calling `children` on the `ActorContext`. This should be enough for your use case.

http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/ActorContext.html#children--